# How to give value for binding field in infopath form?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, infopath

I have 6 radio button and each radio button has values in InfoPath form. Those radio buttons binding to "Email Group Type"field, But "Email Group Type" field has no value(Its empty).

I want to give a value for "Group Type"?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For each radio button, you should do the following:**

- Right Click on the first radio button > `Change Binding`.

[image]

- Select the `Email Group Type` Field.

[image]

- Again right click on the same radio button > Option Button Property.

[image]

- At value when selected, set the exact corresponding value in the choice field.

[image]

- Repeat the above steps for all radio buttons you have.
- Save > Publish.
- Test your form, the selected value should be now reflected to the choice field.